# max_question issue RDS AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS RDS instance of mysql and I am getting the following error

> ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions'
>   resource (current value: 1)

I can log into the mysql instance over ssh and change db, but I can't execute any sql statements even when I log in using root, I still get the above error.

I have also tried

```
update user set max_questions=0;
```

And continue to get the same error.

Does anyone know how to update the max_questions?
Do I need to upgrade the RDS instance class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you `UPDATE mysql.user` directly, it doesn't take effect until you do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` (or alternatively restart mysqld).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html

You must have the `RELOAD` privilege to run the `FLUSH` command.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I have attempted to FLUSH PRIVILEGES and I get the same error. I have also restarted the RDS instance and still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

This article will help you solve this issue. Make sure that you reconnect after changing max_questions.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_questions=0 WHERE User='root';
flush privileges;
```

[Modify the ‘max_questions’ resource value in MySQL](https://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-modify-the-max_questions-resource-value-in-mysql/)

[EDIT after comment]

To verify that the change has been made, execute the following command:

```
select user, max_questions from user;
```

Comment: Thanks John, however I still get the same error. I have tried this solution.

Comment: I modified my answer to include a statement to verify that the change was actually made.

Comment: Thanks again John, I get the same error when I execute 
`select user, max_questions from user;`

Comment: I am using AWS RDS Aurora DB instance.